# Why does integer comparison in a Python tuple give different answers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, comparison

When I try to compare two tuples in the below way, I get a different output each time. Why is that?

```py
>>> print((23,12,1234)<=(19,9,2468))
False
    
>>> print((1234,12,23)<=(2468,9,19))
True
```

Comment: What did you hope that it would do instead, Vinay? If you say that, then maybe somebody can find a way to do what you want.

Comment: can you explain it please with my question @pacharan

Comment: Vinay, your question has been closed now as a duplicate - please see the question that has been linked, as that should contain the answers that you need.